# Use django sorl-thumbnail with django form-utils

Tags: python, django, django-forms, sorl-thumbnail

How do I implement sorl thumbnailing in django form utils?

So the form utils documentation says this about its ImageWidget:

> (Thumbnails only available if
>   sorl-thumbnail is installed; otherwise
>   the full-size image is displayed).

However, I can't seem to implement it. I tried using sorl's ImageField in models, it breaks the form-utils' ImageWidget and I can't get my head around using it in a template when all I have in the template is this:

```
<li class="field_upload">
    {{ form.image.errors }}
    <label for="id_image" class="top">{{  form.image.label }}</label>
    {{ form.image }}
</li>
```

form utils has an option that says:

> ImageWidget accepts a keyword
>   argument, template. This is a string
>   defining how the image thumbnail and
>   the file input widget are rendered
>   relative to each other. The template
>   string should contain variable
>   interpolation markers %(input)s and
>   %(image)s. The default value is
>   %(input)s
> %(image)s

which in code looks like this:

```
pic = forms.ImageField(
    widget=ImageWidget(template='%(image)s<br />%(input)s'))
```

but I can't still figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in your form class definition you are naming the `ImageField` as `pic`, but then in your template you are attempting to refer to the field with `form.image`.

Try just using the standard Django form renderer for now by putting `{{form}}` in your template--if that works then you know it's just a problem with your templating.

---

The SORL thumbnail library should only need to be accessible on your Django project's Python Path (along with the Python Image Library).

To check to see whether or not these libraries are available for your Django project, goto your project's root directory and run...

```
$ python manage.py shell
>> import sorl.thumbnail
>> import PIL
```

If neither of those imports throw `ImportError`s then they are properly installed.

---

Also, maybe include some more code, like the entire form as you have it defined in `forms.py`.